# Kernel module compilation error

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, make

I am getting an error, whenever I am trying to compile the module, as below:

```
sudo make

make -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/build -I m=/home/shakti/Drivers/hello_param modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-45-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:232: recipe for target 'archscripts' failed
make[1]: *** [archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-45-generic'
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Help me out Please .
I have tried so many options.

Comment: `m=/home/shakti/Drivers/hello_param` should probably be `M=/home/shakti/Drivers/hello_param` in your Makefile ...

Answer (score -2):

**i386 headers required:**

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-*(kernel version)*:i386
```

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.4.0-42:i386
```